# I am trying to extract retailer locations from a certain website

Tags: web-crawler, spl

Is it possible to tap into the database or export all store locations from a given website instead of copying and pasting?
For example, I need to retrieve all retailer locations from this site http://goo.gl/kQkE28.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. That's usually called "scraping" the site. It violates the Terms of Service of many sites (I haven't checked that one) and is much too large of a topic for a Stackoverflow Q&A. You might want to start by Googling for "building a web scraper" or something along those lines.

The other thing you could do is write to them and politely ask for the list. Depending on what you want to do with it, they might just give it to you.

Comment: Thank you for the tips Brian, I will start by talking to them.